# Stream does not support seek operations

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-post

I'm trying to POST to a website where the only parameter needed is "description."  I believe it has something to do with the way that I am encoding my data.  Am I missing something/going about this the wrong way?

```
string postData = String.Format("description=" + description + "&");
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
wr.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
wr.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
wr.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

Stream postStream = wr.GetRequestStream();
postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
postStream.Close();

WebResponse response = await wr.GetResponseAsync();
HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
using (var stm = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stm))
    {
        var content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        reader.Close();
        stm.Close();
        return content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use HttpClient instead?

Comment: As a side note, your use of `String.Format` like that seems quite pointless...

Answer (score 3):

The stream you are trying to read apparently doesn't support seeking. You can also verify that programmatically through its [`CanSeek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canseek(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

If you want the same data in a stream that you can seek, consider reading the entirety of your current stream to a `byte[]` buffer, then constructing a [`MemoryStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) out of that buffer for use with your `StreamReader`.